# Wrong assumption that text is in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I am writing a document in text mode and I wish to refer to a variable in some separate software file. But when I try to typeset the document Latex seems to think that the name of the variable is in math mode.

If I write

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}
 
The name of the proposed variable is log_acceptance.
 
\end{document}
```

I get the following message on the console:

```
./mre.tex:5: Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.5 The name of the proposed variable is log_acceptance.
```

If I change my text to

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}
 
The name of the proposed variable is log.

\end{document}
```

then that is typeset correctly as text.

How can I tell Latex to stop thinking that log_acceptance is math?

Comment: It does! Many thanks. The specific solution from amongst the many discussed there is to use {\_}. That does the job for me.

Comment: (you probably mean `{\_}`.) I totally don't understand why people use that instead of just `\_`. What's the difference!?

Comment: Underline is to insert subscript in math mode, for example, `x_1`.

Comment: If you are using OpTeX (instead LaTeX) then you can simply write: `The name of the proposed variable is log_acceptance. \bye`. No problem.